# How to hide the app name in foreground notification?

Tags: android, android-studio, foreground, foreground-service, foregroundnotification

I have developed a simple GPS tracking app that using foreground service to keep the app alive. There will be a notification showing that my app is running, but how can I hide the app name beside the logo? I only want the logo without showing the app name.

[image]

Comment: Want to change just the name or hide the notification?

Comment: Just change the name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep the service active in the foreground you can create your own notification and customize it as you like.

You can use this example code as a base.

```
 lateinit var notificationBuilder: Notification
    private fun setNotification(title: String, descr: String) {
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this, 0, Intent(
                this,
                MainActivity::class.java
            ), 0
        )
        createNotificationChannel()
        notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "misc")
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(descr)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_nordic_icon)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build()
        startForeground(1, notificationBuilder)
    }

    lateinit var manager: NotificationManager
    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val serviceChannel = NotificationChannel(
                "misc",
                "Foreground Service Channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            )
            manager = getSystemService(
                NotificationManager::class.java
            )
            manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel)
        }
    }
```

And call it inside your service like:

```
setNotification(
   "My title",
    "A notification description"
)
```

Official doc [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications).

**Update**

You can hide the notification using a configuration like:

```
serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
 "misc",
 "Foreground Service Channel",
 NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_UNSPECIFIED
);

notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "misc")
 .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MIN)
 .setContentTitle(title)
 .setContentText(descr)
 .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
 .build();
```

Remember to mark your answer as correct if it helped you. Thank you.

Comment: thanks for this sample, but what if i want to hide the entire foreground notification？ Does it mean I also need to create my own notification and make it hidden?

Comment: I updated the answer with the code to hide the foreground notification.